# Issues deploying application on websphere 7

Tags: websphere-7

I am getting problems starting my application on Websphere 7.

The application has jsp, jspx files.

The application works fine on tomcat.
However when I try to start application on web sphere 7, I get following errors in the logs

[29/08/11 06:39:44:988 IST] 0000000b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppinitializeExtensionProcessors SRVE0280E: Extension processor failed to initialize in factory

```
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser.endElement(TldParser.java:396)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.xml.ParserFactory.parseDocument(ParserFactory.java:102)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:315)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser.parseTLD(TldParser.java:266)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadWebXmlMap(TagLibraryCache.java:163)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.<init>(TagLibraryCache.java:102)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.<init>(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:203)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionProcessor.<init>(WASJSPExtensionProcessor.java:70)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionFactory.createProcessor(WASJSPExtensionFactory.java:250)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionFactory.createExtensionProcessor(AbstractJSPExtensionFactory.java:75)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeExtensionProcessors(WebApp.java:1241)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:339)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:292)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:99)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:167)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:722)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:607)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1162)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1313)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:938)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2092)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:437)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:105)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:928)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

[29/08/11 06:39:45:003 IST] 0000000b webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeTargetMappings SRVE0269W: No Extension Processor found for handling JSPs

I checked the tld files in web.xml and they all exist.

Any idea what can be the problem ?

Comment: Note it is actually giving a null pointer exception ([29/08/11 06:39:44:988 IST] 0000000b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeExtensionProcessors SRVE0280E: Extension processor failed to initialize in factory [com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionFactory@74af74af]: java.lang.NullPointerException
)

Comment: Did you try a newer fix pack level of WAS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this exact same error and it turned out to be some invalid elements defined in the TLD XML. I compared the TLD I was given against the DTD it declared to be valid against and noticed some discrepancies. Also, WebSphere did not like that `<info>` had embedded HTML tags in it. Fixing those problems eliminated this exception.